# How to add third-party components to Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio

I'm not very expert of Visual Studio (2015). I'm developing a simple "ASP.NET Web Forms Site".
Say I want to add in one page the following components:

http://js.nicdn.de/bootstrap/formhelpers/docs/index.html

There are a downloadable zip and a github project.
What is the recommended way **in VisualStudio** to import such a third-party item in a ASP website?

I mean: I have to manually put js, css, img files into the folders of my project or there is a managed way in Visual Studio to do this?

Comment: Opened your provided link, there's link to [git-hub project](https://github.com/winmarkltd/BootstrapFormHelpers). Then there is link to [project home page](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/), there is link to [Support](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/support/). And now there you can find [Getting Started](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/gettingstarted/#jquery-plugins) section...

Comment: I've already read that page, but it shows the usual method to add items to a website. My question is if there is a _specific_ tool in VisualStudio. For example I know it uses the `ScriptManager` to import scripts.

Comment: You asked "What is the recommended way to import" the recommended way is the way creator suggests.

Comment: The creator doesn't suggest anything for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Use NuGet.
Just right click on the solution or right click on the desired project and from the context menu click "Manage NuGet Packages". There you can search for a package and install it super easy. You can also install NuGet packages via the package manager console if you prefer command line interface.

Comment: And the package is where on NUGET?

Comment: What do you mean by 'where on NUGET' lol ?
There is a search box, so search for the package and install it.

Comment: The OP mentioned a project that is not available via Nuget.

Comment: As far as I can see it in the package manager bootstrap is available since 2012 via NuGet.